# Need qemu to run headless on host, but still forward graphical output via x11

Tags: ssh, xorg, qemu, linux-kvm

I have a headless host with qemu installed. I can ssh into the host, and forward x11 so I can view graphical output.

However, when I try to run qemu, I get the following error:

```
Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting
```

The `-display` none and `-nographic` arguments don't help, because I *do* want the graphical output sent over the SSH tunnel. But I don't have a monitor on the host machine.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this? Also, unfortunately, vnc is **not** an option per the organization's policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As counterintuitive as it seems VNC **is** an option: Run the guest with a VNC console, which you completely ignore, then use X over ssh to do the normal work.

We are running this setup with literally hundreds of Linux, BSD and Windows (RDP instead of X) guests and it works fine.

You can simply lock down VNC binding to localhost, if you are concerned about the security aspects.

Comment: I apologize, I meant VNC isn't an option as a matter of organization policy. But it's starting to sound like that might be the only way.

Comment: Just use VNC and treat it as /dev/null. This makes the guest happy and doesn't stand in the way. Besides: If you manage to make your guest's network unusable (typo in /etc/network/interfaces), you have a way out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try XMing on Windows and rule it out, or just RDP by default?

Comment: We use XMing widely to allow virt-manager on Windows. Together with a `plink` script it's a treat.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need VNC
just use -nographic and ssh tunnel (works for me, so it should work for you too)
-nographic means that qemu doesn't simulate a GPU, but if you ssh forward the screen anyway then it doesn't matter, less overhead than VNC too (not that it matters much)
you basically tell the guest programs that "hey, you need a screen? I have a screen for you" and then send all the screen data through ssh, instead of using a physical device on the guest

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for me over SSH.